# When does NSSpeechSynthesizer finish speaking?

Tags: macos, cocoa

How can I know when NSSpeechSynthesizer finishes speaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You read the [documentation for NSSpeechSynthesizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSpeechSynthesizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and discover the [-speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate/speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking:) delegate method.

Then, if you're not sure how to use delegate methods, you read more [documentation about Cocoa delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW26).

Then, if you still can't get it to work, you post a separate question here including as many details as you can about what you've tried (hint: code, a description of your app and how things are connected, etc.) and what isn't working (ie, the delegate method is never called, it crashes, etc.).